# Custom overseas payment Gateway

Tags: wordpress, paypal, payment-gateway, credit-card, web-development-server

I`m fairly new to this and I`d like to know how possible it is. I need to place a payment gateway on my website which will allow customers to pay to an organization of choice anywhere allover the world. I would like that payment gateway transfer it to the organization`s bank account, with a percentage going to our corporate bank account. I would like to know how possible is that.
Please let me know if more details are needed. Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking about **possibilities** and **is not a concrete coding question**. If you want to know if something is possible you should **research it** and **attempt to implement it**. If you have issues while doing this you then can ask a **specific** question, **showing the code you have written**, your expected results, and your actual results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into PayPal [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#adaptive), specifically [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) and [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

Alternatively, you could go with [Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#wpp) / [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec) and then setup an [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) solution to automate the process of distributing funds accordingly after a payment hits your account.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that will be a great place to start researching. Do you think There will be any limitations doing this, as I`ll be using WordPress. And will that need someone who is highly skilled in web development?